# Laravel 4 Namespace without \

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, laravel-4

Best everyone,

There is one thing in Laravel 4 I just can't understand if you create a namespace in my case `cms` and you want to use for instance `View::make` or `Input::all()`
laravel wil tell you it could not be found what is correct since those methods are in the global namespace and not in `cms` so to get it to work you can refer to it with adding a backslash before the method that will it wil user the global namespace. however i find that confusing isn't there a way to have a `use` or something that imports all the `Input, Hash, Redirect` enz.. So you could use it without adding `\`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I completely follow, do you mean: using View::all() without doing \View::all() in a cms Namespaced file?

If so you can import namespaces by using the **use** keyword and alias them by using the **as** keyword

e.g.

```
use MyNameSpace\View;            // Imports only
use MyNameSpace\View as MyView;  // Imports and Aliases

class {
    ....
}
```

For more details please see http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: yes but in this case it would be adding it for ALL the functions so, View, Request, Auth, etc.. so that is exactly what i would want to avoid.